# Access element of list of arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of data made up of arrays. I want to able to access each element of these arrays. However, when I try to access each element of one of the lists I instead get a whole list returned i.e.

```
>>> vec_data[0]
'[array([129.1203,  65.5152, -15.7962]), array([ -75.8793,  -27.2767, -136.3468]), array([  98.54  , -110.7603,  187.9171]), array([ 83.9628, 126.839 , -61.4756]), array([ -63.1397, -216.348 , -165.1392]), array([ 32.8174,  45.1573, 146.6547]), array([65.2439, 82.8289, 13.3427]), array([  -8.481 ,  -38.3387, -138.1786]), array([-223.8824,   86.1375,   -2.5446]), array([211.8308,  51.894 ,  89.5078]), array([  21.4793, -177.2219,   -0.573 ])]\n'
```

I then tried vec_data[0][0] hoping to get [129.1203,  65.5152, -15.7962] returned but instead got:

```
>>> vec_data[0][0]
'['
```

Can anyone provide any insight on how I may get back the output I want from this list?

I have attached a small excerpt of the data below to aid the problem.

```
['[array([129.1203,  65.5152, -15.7962]), array([ 83.094 , 135.5689,  57.7153]), array([  97.337 , -158.2453,   26.0811]), array([  31.3163,  121.7492, -100.4891]), array([ 60.797 ,  20.4243, -45.3821]), array([  -1.9805, -145.0236,  -57.6177]), array([116.4612,  18.3822, -99.8011]), array([38.402 , 13.7894, 85.094 ]), array([-321.057 ,  147.0128,  173.035 ]), array([  99.6488,  -74.9626, -110.7028]), array([ 134.3792, -110.4547,   -8.8729])]\n', '[array([ -67.876  ,  -28.46764, -118.16426]), array([ 58.368  , 107.64964,  90.12756]), array([ 102.6007, -165.1867,   26.1187]), array([  39.58716,  124.4238 , -106.68995]), array([ 58.19804,  18.7423 , -40.15905]), array([  -4.9479, -151.5177,  -56.3511]), array([ 99.946 ,  27.8355, -89.1489]), array([51.115, -3.302, 80.843]), array([-326.252 ,  170.7748,  168.0119]), array([ 120.9826,  -91.66  , -116.6699]), array([114.7974, -82.5404,   2.0438])]\n', '[array([ -28.196  ,  -14.69983, -149.5836 ]), array([ 54.399  , 108.75513, 106.2178 ]), array([  93.0723, -146.1217,   27.1268]), array([  15.1398,  104.9325, -128.3365]), array([ 89.2691,   2.3471, -21.0604]), array([ -15.2423, -155.4835,  -28.2395]), array([ 86.8051, -18.2533, -74.2126]), array([73.194 , 60.0037, 67.0507]), array([-314.68  ,  170.6532,  145.9454]), array([  69.4455,  -98.9357, -135.0111]), array([147.9465, -88.8198,  36.5976]
```

EDIT:

using the method suggested by revliscano:

```
import re
import json


string = vec_data[0]
r = re.sub('array\((\[.+?\])\)', lambda x: x.groups()[0], string)
r = r.replace('\n', '')
list_ = json.loads(r)
```

Give me the desired output for vec_data[0] however, I want to get this to loop over all of vec_data - any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like you have no array here but a string instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a way of not putting this data into your program as a string, that would be ideal, but I believe that the following should work to convert your data into a better format.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array
vec_data = eval(vec_data)
```

After doing this with your sample code I got a list of arrays.

If you want this to be in a list format instead, you could replace `array = np.array` with `array = list`, but by the looks of your input data, it was probably originally a numpy array.

Comment: Should note that if the source of the data is untrusted, [using `eval` is a very bad idea](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: I tried this but received an error:
>>> array = np.array 
>>> vec_data = eval(vec_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: @raby Try `v = eval(vec_data[0])` instead. duckboycool is using different variable names which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @wjandrea For me, it worked if I tried either the first snippet from `vec_data[0]` or the sample at the bottom, which I believe was from the whole set. But if it is a list, then you'd probably want to use `vec_data = [eval(x) for x in vec_data]`.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* The following answer does not have anything to do with numpy arrays, but it finds a way to parse the string you have in `vec_data[0]`, so that it can be accesible and used as a **list**, which at the end I think is what you are trying to do.

We're going to be using regex (through the `re` module) and the `json` module to achieve this.

If all the items of `vec_data` have similar values (strings that need to be parsed, just like `vec_data[0]`), then you can use this solution as a function, and use a list comprehension to iterate `vec_data`, calling that function on each item of it:

```py
import re
import json


def parse_array(string):
    r = re.sub('array\((\[.+?\])\)', lambda x: x.groups()[0], string)
    r = r.replace('\n', '')
    list_ = json.loads(r)
    return list_


new_vec_data = [parse_array(string) for string in vec_data]
```

**output for `print(new_vec_data[0][0])`:**

```
[129.1203, 65.5152, -15.7962]
```

Comment: trying to iterate this method over all of vec_data using the following method. Is there a better way to do this? 

>>> tmp_l = [] 
>>> for i in range(len(vec_data)): 
...     string = vec_data[i]
...     r = re.sub('array\((\[.+?\])\)', lambda x: x.groups()[i], string)
...     r = r.replace('\n','')
...     tmp_l.append(json.loads(r))

Comment: So all of `vec_data` items are similar? i.e: strings that need to be parsed?

Comment: I have updated my answer, considering that what I asked above is true.

Answer (score -1):

Try vec_data[0][0][0] to access the first element of first list

Comment: This would give the same `[` output as `vec_data[0][0]` since it's a string.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
import re
import json

output = []
for i in vec_data:
    string = vec_data[0]
    r = re.sub('array\((\[.+?\])\)', lambda x: x.groups()[0], string)
    r = r.replace('\n', '')
    output.append(json.loads(r))

print(output)
```

This way, you will get a list of data list.

If you want a single list with all the data, you can use **extend** instead such as,

```
import re
import json

output = []
for i in vec_data:
    string = vec_data[0]
    r = re.sub('array\((\[.+?\])\)', lambda x: x.groups()[0], string)
    r = r.replace('\n', '')
    output.extend(json.loads(r))

print(output)
```